# check to see if a JFrame is open

Tags: java, swing, jframe, chat

I am trying to create a chat client for a program of mine and I would like to open a new window for each chat (A & B will not be in the same window as A & C)  I have psudocode for what I am trying to do but unsure on how to write it.

Chat client:

```
inputstream.read()
Read who message from
If (chat window arleady open with person from)
{
    Add Message to output section of the window
{
else if (chat window not open)
{
    Open new chat window with person from
    Display message in new chat window
}
```

To do this, the thing I have thought about is storing the IPs in an array and then whenever the client gets a message it would look through the array to see if the IP was stored.  If it is stored, the window should already be open, otherwise the window needs to be opened.  I can program this by using the defaultonclose command from JFrame to just call a removal of the IP when the window is closed, but here are the problems I am running into.

1. Once I search the array for the IP addresses, If the window is already open (say I have A B and C talking to D) how do I insure if C sends a message that it gets placed in the C window?

1.1 I have thought about spawning a new thread, naming the thread, and then when a message comes in pass it into the the thread that matches the name, but I am not sure about how to do that.  I have read the names of threads before but never passed something into a specific thread.

Is there anyway to do this easier without downloading extra libs?

Comment: How does your client look like? What do you consider a window?

Comment: the client currently controls an inventory database, however I am trying to add a chat service to it.  I have the database commands and message commands traveling the same socket and then spawning off into either inventory handler or chat handler based on a field i'm calling "type".  I consider every JFrame a "window".

Comment: I am still not sure I understood your problem. Is it about managing which conversation is shown in which window?

Comment: I really have 2 problems.  #1 how to check to see if a window is open, and #2 how to get data into the correct window.  If I have a chat service open, and I am talking to 3 different people in 3 different windows, how do I make sure when I get a message from person 2 that it goes into the window that belongs to the conversation between the 2 of us.

Comment: You should maybe split your question to address one problem per question.
Here is a hint about your problem: Your chat service could keep track of your conversations and windows. You could for example use a Map to track senders and their conversations. Also you could use a Map to store which Window is "open" or not.

Comment: I hope you not making your Server side chat also. I will keep server side for sending messages here and there, instead of making it to plug into the same area. For this situation in hand, I guess you can use `HashMap`, simply provide a code as say 1 refers to A and 2 for B, now if A sends a message to B, it will be like `12My Message`, now the first two letters can be used to distinguish, who send the message and to whom it is meant to be delivered. And if B is sending one to C, then it will be like `23B's Message`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- don't use `JFrame` for another window, because you can't to set `parent v.s.owner`, use `JDialog` instead
- then `JFrame.getOwnedWindows()` returns all instances of `JDialog(s)` where is used [JDialog(myFrame owner)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog%29)
- in all cases `Window[] allWindows = Window.getWindows();` returns all instances from current JVM, returns all instances of `(J)Frames`, `(J)Dialogs`, `(J)Windows` or `JOptionsPanes`

Comment: so if i get this right I would do JDialog(Frame owner,
       String title) where owner would be the person who sent the message and title would be what is in the tile bar of the window? and then I add my JTextAreas, buttons, etc to that just like I would a JFrame?

Comment: 1) owner could be JFrame 2) String title could be person 3) rest is correct,

Comment: so I construct my JFrame as normal and pass the JFrame as the "owner"? or does the JDialog become the new Frame?  to clarify do i do JDialog JD = new JDialog (JFrame myFrame, String Matt) and then JD.add(text) or myFrame.add(text)?  I see container calls in the write up, so I'm assuming JD.add, but I would like clarification before I go and write all the code.